# Core Data saving to Only One Entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm a bit confused about saving entities using Core Data. I'm making a screen that will allow users to save their settings (contact information), which can be changed later if they wish.

From what I understand, my code below will save multiple entities each time the 'save' button is pressed.

```
- (IBAction)saveSettings:(id)sender {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context =
    [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *userSettings;


    userSettings = [NSEntityDescription
                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserSettings"
                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [userSettings setValue: _firstName.text forKey:@"firstName"];
    [userSettings setValue: _lastName.text forKey:@"lastName"];
    [userSettings setValue: _userEmail.text forKey:@"userEmail"];
    [userSettings setValue: _zipCode.text forKey:@"zipCode"];
}
```

What I don't understand how to do is save one entity, and then change the values of the attributes later on whenever the user types in new values in the appropriate text fields and presses 'save'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - because you use `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:`, a new UserSettings object is created each time that method is run.  What you probably want to do is to fetch the existing settings from the database, update your textFields with that data, present the view and let the user amend the details as necessary, and then (when they press the save button), save that data back to the database.

I would add userSettings as a property:

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObject *userSettings;
```

and in your method delete the declaration of userSettings, and the line where you use `insertNewObjectForEntityForName`.

Then create a new method to handle fetching the data from the database and assigning it to your textFields, as follows:

```
-(void)loadSettings {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"UserSettings"];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
    if (results == nil) {
        // some error handler here
    }
    if ([results count] > 0) {
        userSettings = [results lastObject];
        _firstName.text = [userSettings valueForKey:@"firstName"];
        _lastName.text  = [userSettings valueForKey:@"lastName"];
        _userEmail.text = [userSettings valueForKey:@"userEmail"];
        _zipCode.text = [userSettings valueForKey:@"zipCode"];
    } else {
        // set your text fields to some defaults values??
    }
}
```

Call this method when your view controller loads, in the `viewDidLoad` method.  I've assumed that you will normally have only one `UserSettings` object (hence `lastObject` will be the only object!).  If you could have many UserSettings objects, you would need to filter the fetch to get only the one you want.  To do that you would need to set a `predicate` for the fetch - look at the documentation for `NSPredicate`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this makes a lot of sense!
I've almost finished these changes, but have a few questions; would you be able to discuss in chat at all?

Comment: Sure - can you set up a session?

Comment: Yup! Here's the link:
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65007/core-data-saving-to-only-one-entity

Comment: Thanks again for the chat! 
I do have one other Core Data related question; but I'm not sure it's SO appropriate (it's more of a pros/cons/comparison question then a code question). Would it be possible to chat via email?

Comment: Sure - I have added details to the above chat session - slightly obfuscated to avoid spam, but I'm sure you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually overwriting those properties everytime you "set". The correct way to store individual properties is to assign them and save, like so:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *userSettings;


userSettings = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserSettings"
              inManagedObjectContext:context];


userSettings.firstName = _firstName.text;
userSettings.lastName  = _lastName.text;
userSettings.userEmail = _userEmail.text;
userSettings.zipCode   = _zipCode.text;


NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Error Saving: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Hey Marcos, thanks for your reply. I see the difference, but I'm not sure I understand why you need to assign and save rather then set properties.